# Tracking and Logging Changes in Backup Addresses with Entity Framework .Net

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, change-tracking

```
 public async Task LogChanges<TEntity>(TEntity entity, bool isCreation = false, string fName = "", string lName = "")
     where TEntity : class
 {
     var originalValues = isCreation ? null : GetOriginalValues(entity);
     DocumentTypes documentType;

     if (entity is DocA)
     {
         documentType = DocumentTypes.A;
     }
     else if (entity is DocB)
     {
         documentType = DocumentTypes.B;
     }
     else if (entity is DocC)
     {
         documentType = DocumentTypes.C;
     }
     else if (entity is DocD)
     {
         documentType = DocumentTypes.D;
     }
     else
     {
         throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported entity type");
     }

     var entry = isCreation ? null : Conn.Entry(entity);
     var modifiedProperties = isCreation
          ? entry.Properties
              .ToDictionary(p => p.Metadata.Name, p => new
              {
                  Original = p.OriginalValue,
                  Current = p.CurrentValue
              })
          : entry.Properties
              .Where(p => p.IsModified)
              .ToDictionary(p => p.Metadata.Name, p => new
              {
                  Original = p.OriginalValue,
                  Current = p.CurrentValue
              });

     var addressProperties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
         .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(BackUpAddress))
         .Select(p => new
         {
             Property = p,
             Original = isCreation ? null :  p.GetValue(entity),
             Current = p.GetValue(entity)
         })
         .Where(p => p.Original != p.Current)
         .ToDictionary(p => p.Property.Name, p => new
         {
             p.Original,
             p.Current
         });

     if (addressProperties != null)
     {
         foreach (var prop in addressProperties)
         {
             modifiedProperties.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
         }
     }
        private PropertyValues GetOriginalValues<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
        {
            return Conn.Entry(entity).OriginalValues.Clone();
        }
```

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("edit")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(DocEditDto postModel)
 {
     var item = _repo.GetDoc(postModel.Id);

     #region Address
     if (postModel.BackUpAddress!= null)
     {
         foreach (var address in postModel.BackUpAddress)
         {
             var fieldNo = address.FieldNo;
             int? addressId = null;
             if (fieldNo != 0)
             {
                 switch (fieldNo)
                 {
                     case 1:
                         addressId = item.Address1Id;
                         break;
                     case 5:
                         addressId = item.Address5Id;
                         break;
                     case 6:
                         addressId = item.Address6Id;
                         break;
                     case 12:
                         addressId = item.Address12Id;
                         break;
                     case 13:
                         addressId = item.Address13Id;
                         break;
                     case 17:
                         addressId = item.Address17Id;
                         break;
                     default:
                         break;
                 }

                 if (addressId.HasValue)
                 {
                     var existingAddress = await _repoAddress.GetItemAsync(addressId.Value);
                     if (existingAddress != null)
                     {
                         existingAddress.Address1 = address.Address1;
                         existingAddress.CityName = address.CityName;
                         existingAddress.Address2 = address.Address2;
                         existingAddress.CompanyAddressId = address.CompanyAddressId;
                         existingAddress.PostalCode = address.PostalCode;
                         existingAddress.AddressId = address.AddressId;
                         existingAddress.CompanyName = address.CompanyName;
                         existingAddress.CountryName = address.CountryName;
                         existingAddress.CountryCode = address.CountryCode;
                         existingAddress.WasteLicenceNumber = address.WasteLicenceNumber;
                         existingAddress.EGNumber = address.EGNumber;
                         existingAddress.LicenceNumber = address.LicenceNumber;
                         existingAddress.Tel = address.Tel;
                         await _repoAddress.EditAsync(existingAddress);
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Address backupAddress = new Address
                     {
                         Address1 = address.Address1,
                         CityName = address.CityName,
                         Address2 = address.Address2,
                         CompanyAddressId = address.CompanyAddressId,
                         PostalCode = address.PostalCode,
                         AddressId = address.AddressId,
                         CountryName = address.CountryName,
                         CompanyName = address.CompanyName,
                         EGNumber = address.EGNumber,
                         WasteLicenceNumber = address.WasteLicenceNumber,
                         LicenceNumber = address.LicenceNumber,
                         CountryCode = address.CountryCode,
                         Tel = address.Tel,
                     };
                     await _repoAddress.CreateAsync(backupAddress);
                     switch (fieldNo)
                     {
                         case 1:
                             item.Address1Id = backupAddress.Id;
                             break;
                         case 5:
                             item.Address5Id = backupAddress.Id;
                             break;
                         case 6:
                             item.Address6Id = backupAddress.Id;
                             break;
                         case 12:
                             item.Address12Id = backupAddress.Id;
                             break;
                         case 13:
                             item.Address13Id = backupAddress.Id;
                             break;
                         case 17:
                             item.Address17Id = backupAddress.Id;
                             break;
                         default:
                             break;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     #endregion
await _repoLog.LogChanges(item, isCreation: false, fName:"firstname" , lName: "lastname");
```

```
    public class DocA : BaseEntity
    {
        public int? Address1Id { get; set; }
        public BackUpAddress Address1 { get; set; }

        public int? Address5Id { get; set; }
        public BackUpAddress Address5 { get; set; }
        ....
}
public class BackUpAddress : BaseEntity
{

    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyAddressId { get; set; }
    public CompanyAddress CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have four documents, namely docA, docB,docC and docD. In these documents, there are multiple addresses, which I have centralized in a common table since they are shared among all. For instance, in the docA class, there are addresses 1, 5, and others, each associated with a unique ID. I can access the old and new values of other variables within docA through the change tracker, but I cannot observe changes within backup addresses. Additionally, I cannot access the old and new values, making the where clause ineffective. When there is a change in the backup addresses, I want to capture their old and new values and log them into a separate log table if they differ. Where is my mistake, and how can I resolve this issue? I appreciate your assistance.

I provided the entity obtained from the entry and tried to take its copy to inspect the contents, but I was unsuccessful. However, I can detect changes in variables within the DocA table that are not related. Additionally, I can log these changes.

Comment: Well based on your scenario and description its hard to investigate your issue as the shared code snippet are less readable. Could you please share a minimum reproducible sample in order to investigate your current issue accordingly?